# Indecomposable modules over nilpotent Lie algebras

Tags: modules, lie-algebras

Is something known about indecomposable (finite-dimensional) modules over nilpotent Lie algebras (the ground field is algebraically closed) ? In particular, I wonder:

> Is the following statement true ?
>
> **S)** *Let $V$ be an indecomposable (finite-dimensional) module over nilpotent $k$-Lie algebras ($k$ is algebraically closed), then there is a unique character $c: \frak{g}\to \mathbb{k}$ such that, for all $g\in \frak{g}$, the operator 
>   $$
> g_V-c(g)Id_V\in End_k(V)
> $$
>   is nilpotent.*

Comment: Now asked also on MO: [About indecomposability and nilpotence](https://mathoverflow.net/q/295421).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true and done in Bourbaki, *Lie groups and Lie algebras*, beginning of Chap VII. See esp. Prop 9 in §1.3 (on decomposition of modules over nilpotent Lie algebras).

A few details. Fix $K$ a field of characteristic zero. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over $K$ and $V$ a finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-module, given by a Lie algebra homomorphism $\pi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathrm{End}_K(V)$. For a Lie algebra homomorphism $\lambda:\mathfrak{g}\to K$, define $$M^\lambda(V)=\{x\in V\mid \exists n:\forall g\in\mathfrak{g}:\;(\pi(g)-\lambda(g)\mathrm{Id}_V)^nx=0\}.$$

Then Proposition 9 of the above-mentioned reference states that when $\lambda$ varies, these are $\mathfrak{g}$-submodules, they generate their direct sum, and that if $\pi(g)$ is $K$-trigonalizable for every $g$ (which holds when $K$ is algebraically closed), then the direct sum is $V$.

In particular when $K$ is algebraically closed and $M$ is indecomposable, this forces $V=M^\lambda(V)$ for some $\lambda$.

Comment: Perfect ! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I am not sure that the hypothesis about characteristic zero is necessary though. Bourbaki do not seem to require this there. I will, when I can take the opportunity (i.e. when I get some free time), check the logical chain (without characteristic zero but with algebraic closure) or find a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a lot known. What do you want to know? In low dimensions we can obtain indecomposable modules like here,

[Indecomposable representations of Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934033/indecomposable-representations-of-lie-algebra/934053)

by passing to the nilpotent radical $\mathfrak{n}$ of the Borel subalgebra.

Comment: I added what I would like to know within the question (+1)